# when adding data to Firebase database onFailure method is never called

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, exception

```
ref.push().setValue(user)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.d("test","sucess");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("test","fail");
                    }
                });
```

I am testing my project without internet connection. When I try to add some data to Firebase, I would guess that onFailure method would be called with some NetworkError exception. But that is not happening. What is the problem here? Why is onFailure method never called?

Comment: Are you using [offline capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)?

Comment: No. Why are u asking?